# Correct way to use Kotlin with Command Line and VS Code

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, jetbrains-ide

I have a file `hello.kt` which I'm editing in VSCode. When I tried a simple Hello World:

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, World!");
}
```

and compiled the file with `kotlinc hello.kt` followed by `java HelloKt`, the program worked fine.

However, when I change my file to:

```
fun main() {
    val c = sum(2, 3);
    println("The sum of 2 and 3 is $c");
}
fun sum(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return x + y;
}
```

and run the same commands, I get an error.

```
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt:4)
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 2 more
```

The official [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/getting-started.html#create-your-powerful-application-with-kotlin) suggests installing a full fledged IDE as the first step of learning Kotlin, but what do I need to do if I want to write Kotlin programs (or even full-fledged Kotlin projects) in VSCode?

I am running Kotlin on macOS Catalina, after running `brew install kotlin` . I have Java installed correctly (i.e. on the path, with $JAVA_HOME defined and everything).

Comment: You can have a look at the official documentation for the command line compiiler: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default command for Kotlin is

```
kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
java -jar hello.jar
```

Run with above commands, you will get the right result:

[image]

Comment: Marking this as the answer, for now. But am still wondering if there are any ways similar to the workflow for Java files. For Java, I don't need to create Jars for simple programs. The default workflow (compile using `javac` and `java <name>` ), I was trying to find something equally lightweight to that.

Comment: @shikharraje. Sorry that there's no such settings in Java Extension to meet your needs.